# Not getting clicks in iPad version of my iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad

Using the latest SDK from Apple, I noticed that while running on the ***iPhone*** works fine, the **iPad** version of my application doesn't "accept clicks" on any view/widget that is outside the "bounds" of the standard iPhone screen.

Any idea?

Thanks,
 Reuven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - found it...

All I needed to do was to open MainWindow.xib in Interface Bulder, and in the Window Attributeds palette, to check "Full Screen at Launch".

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla iPhone apps will only accept touches within that little bounds, to reproduce that fact that the iPhone resolution is only 320×480.

To fix it, upgrade your app for iPad.

(Also, make sure you don't hard-code any numbers. For example, use `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds`.)

Comment: using the latest SDK, I can't find the upgrade for iPad option.
Where is it hiding?

Comment: Like I said, this answer doesn't help me in the context of the SDK I have - I don't see this option...

Comment: @Reuven: Right click on the Target, choose "Upgrade current target for iPad".